# jquery: how to animate or ease the shrinking of a DIV that contains a background image and nothing else

Tags: jquery

I have a div that is displaying only its background image:

```
  .foo
{
 height: 55px; width: 33px;
background: url('../images/foo.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position:center; 
background-size: contain;
-moz-background-size: contain;
 color: transparent;
}
```

I want to shrink it to height: 1px; width: 33px, and then, when the shrinking is completed, remove it from the DOM by invoking a callback function when the animation is completed.

I've tried switchClass but removing  .foo removes the background image and the div shrinks instantly, not over the specified duration, and the callback function fires instantly.

Answer (score 2):

Use [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) with a callback function:

```
$(".foo").animate({ height: 1 }, 500, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Where `500` is the duration in milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you for this, and it SHOULD work,  but it is not reliable. It often leaves a vestigial shrunken image on the page, as if the animation's effects were still ongoing when the callback is invoked. That is not your fault, of course, but I am reluctant to accept the answer because the implementation is unreliable.

Comment: Could you provide a live example on http://jsfiddle.net or http://codepen.io/pen so I can check the problem?

I have created a working example on Codepen and it doesn't show that vestigal shrunken image you mentioned:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/igHKC

Comment: OK, let me see if I can put it together. The issue may involve some knockout-jQuery interaction. The item is removed from the DOM indirectly by being removed from a knockout observableArray bound to a container div using foreach binding. Your example seems to work fine. Thanks for the help here. I'm also dealing with maybe a dozen small images, in floated divs.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle that shows a related anomaly. Add 16 cards to your "hand". Delete them at random, paying attention to the number of clicks. Sometimes it takes less than 16 clicks to delete the full hand; more than one card is being removed. http://jsfiddle.net/7z7kP/4/

Comment: I haven't used Knockout. i'd suggest you edit your question and add the Knockout tag. Also, show the relevant JS.